# Dynamic MVC Routing : Action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcroutehandler

I have a Controller named `About` and an Action named `Index`. I want the URL to be like this (action name will be dynamically):

```
www.example.com/about/aaa
www.example.com/about/bbb
www.example.com/about/ccc
```

**Routing**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "About",
    url: "{controller}/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index"}
```

**Controller**

```
public class AboutController : Controller
{
    // GET: /About/
    public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index About</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "About",
    url: "About/{name}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "About",
        action = "Index"
    });
```

Make sure your default route exists and comes after About route

Comment: Its not working. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL: /About/ip

Comment: @Velu make sure your default route exists and comes after About route.

Comment: Thanks its working now. Previously default route is first and then i have About route. After changing the position its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "About",
    url: "about/{name}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional}
```

Comment: Its not working.

 The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /About/ip

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `ActionResult` name as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View(name);
}    

public ActionResult First()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Second()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Action named Firts" "Index", "Home", new {name = "First"}, null)
```